# String of KML needs to be converted to java objects

Tags: java, string, object, kml

I have a string of kml coming in on a request object.  I have used xjc to create the kml java objects.  I am looking for an easy way to create the kml nested java objects from this string.  I could parse the string and create each object in the tree by hand but wouldn't it be cool if there was a library or something that would create the java objects for me?  Something like KmlType type = parseKML(mykmlStringFromTheRequest);  Then type would be a Tree of kml objects.   Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAK http://labs.micromata.de/display/jak/Home will help